# Is Java compiler optimizing and do not create new objects/references if not necessary

Tags: java, memory-management, compiler-optimization

Is Java compiler optimizing and do not create new objects/references if not necessary?

e.g.

```
public class Foo {

    public void foo(Object[] data) {
        for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            Object d = data[i];                     // <-- here
            bar(d);
        }
    }

    private void bar(Object o) {
        //...
    }

}
```

is it the same as:

```
public class Foo {

    public void foo(Object[] data) {
        for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            bar(data[i]);                          // <-- and here
        }
    }

    private void bar(Object o) {
        //...
    }

}
```

in **runtime** ?

Comment: No object creation involved in both snippets ... the only thing that's saved (and yes, probably optimized as is) is the local variable. To see if the compiler actually produces same code, look at the Bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

It's a really complicated topic, what java compiler optimizes and what it does not.

When you compile your code with `javac` it basically does not optimize anything, except some really small fragments. It leaves it untouched so the `JIT compiler` has better knowledge at runtime. Thus looking at bytecode is not really useful.

When your code becomes `hot` when it's called enough times so it's marked for optimization by JIT, complex optimizations are performed. Some people say that code optimized by JIT can be 20 times faster. Depending on the whole context your code from this question can become something completely different if JIT decides so, its execution can even be skipped. JIT is definitely able to do the optimization you ask about, and much much more than that.

Comment: In other words during compilation to bytecode nothing is optimized - am I right?

Comment: Some things are done: like inlining static finals, calculating known expressions and String literal concatenation, switch statements. Also, in Java 9 old string concatenation is replaced with a new usage of `StringConcatFactory`. Those are not really optimizations per se, just some things that can be done without any disadvantage.